# ALternative to seaarch and retrieve image on a server using php

Tags: php, image

I am trying to post a image file's name from a form to the same php page. I want the php code to then search for an image with a similar name and show it in the page. the problem is unless my search string is a sub-string of the file name, my search has no result eg: for Mango.jpg if i search "mango" i wont get an output. Is there any other alternative to implement this funcyionality.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['picname'])){
$picname=$_POST['picname'];
$string =array();
$filePath='images/';  
$dir = opendir($filePath);
while ($file = readdir($dir)) { 
  if (preg_match("/.png/",$file) || preg_match("/.jpg/",$file) || preg_match("/.gif/",$file) ) { 
  $string[] = $file;
  }
 }
while (sizeof($string) != 0){
  $img = array_pop($string);
  $pos = strpos($img,$picname);
  echo $img;
  if($pos === false) { 
    echo "";
   }else{
    echo "<img src='$filePath$img' width='100px' >";
        }
   }
}
?>
<html>

<head>

<title>getting pics</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Enter a product to search</h1>
<form action="<?php print $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="picname" />
    <input type="submit" value="Go!" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with [approximate string comparison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching)

instead of searching an exact matching substring, create a string metric and a scoring system. Assign +1 for every matching letter inside a filename, assign +2 for every matching two-letters string and so on. Assign +N for the entire matching substring, You'll end up with a score value for every filename, sort the list out and grab the first 10 for example.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `file_exists()` function with the same technique you used by concatenating the extensions.

Another solution would be using

```
$result = glob ("./uploads/filename.*");
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
$pos = stripos($img,$picname);
```